# Java AES encryption fails after Badpadding exception

Tags: java, java-security

I am using following code to decrypt cipher text encrypted by 128 bit AES.

```
final IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
final SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

final Cipher cipherSpec = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
cipherSpec.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
cipherSpec.doFinal(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encrypted));
```

My encrypted text is simple one line statement and I am using following key and initial verctor

```
Key = "77696567683763656548616574326F6F"; // 128 bit key, hext string
initVector = "6F68706865726F68563274686F6F3761"; // 16 bytes IV, hex string
```

Everything worked fine except following scenario.

1)Encrypt the plain text using key as the initial vector and initial vector ad the key. Decryption failed with BadPaddingException

2)Encrypt using key as the key and initial vector as the initial vector. Above code decrypts the cipher text without exception but output is garbage. Not what I encrypted.

3)Decrypts again above correctly encrypted cipher text (in 2 step) and now it is decrypted to the correct plain text.

My question is why the decryption fails to decrypt into correct cipher text in step 2 ?

Comment: You're doing something wrong, but it's impossible to guess what from the information given. Show the minimal complete code that exhibits the problem. And don't try to swap key and IV; they are different ideas and that will never work but it will destroy security.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your key, if 128 bits, need to be a 16 character(utf-8) byte array as opposed to 32 characters.  So you'd want to do something like :

```
Key = ("7769656768376365").getBytes("UTF-8");
```